# How to restrict increment button if stock is 10?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am new to Android. I'm trying to restrict increments if the value of `stock` is 10. The count value is set in `textcount` which is a `TextView`. `plus` and `minus` are button for increment and decrement.
stockshow is textview and ITEM_QTY i added in getter setter method

```
plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addtocart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        count++;
        textcount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }
});

minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        count--;
        textcount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }
});
```

stockshow.setText(country.getITEM_QTY());

Comment: When do you want to set the text on `stockshow`?

Comment: stock is coming from getITEM_QTY  @Skizo-ozᴉʞS

Comment: And what's missing now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to make use of the [`setEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled(boolean)) method of `View` to ensure that the `plus` button can no longer be clicked should the stock count be set to 10. Likewise, you'll also want to disable the `minus` button once the stock count reaches 0. You could create a method like this:

```
private void checkBounds() {
    plus.setEnabled(count < 10);
    minus.setEnabled(count > 0);
}
```

And then use it in your listeners like so:

```
plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addtocart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        count++;
        textcount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        checkBounds();
    }
});

minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        count--;
        textcount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        checkBounds();
    }
});
```

Comment: @MichalDodd can i add variable than 10

Comment: On the line `plus.setEnabled(count < 10);`, replace `10` with whatever your variable is called.

Comment: Is `stockShow` a `TextView`? If so, you'll need to use `Integer.valueOf(stockShow.getText().toString());`

Comment: Either that or have your total stock assigned to a separate `int` variable and have the value of that displayed in `stockShow`

Comment: Error:(177, 12) error: bad operand types for binary operator '>'
first type:  int
second type: TextView

Comment: @AbhaNagpure Yeah do what I mentioned above. Get the `Integer` value of the text, or store the value in a separate variable.

Comment: Integer stok = Integer.valueOf(stockshow.getText().toString()  plus.setEnabled ( count > stok); is it right? @MichaelDodd

Comment: That would work. Personally I'd always store `stock` as an `int` and then just display that in `stockShow`, but you can do that.

Comment: String stok = country.getITEM_QTY();
             int abc = Integer.parseInt(stok);
                plus.setEnabled ( count > abc); @MichaelDodd

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main   Process: com.gosellsy.hp.gotrademerchant, PID: 18799
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "134.0" @MichaelDodd crashed

Comment: @AbhaNagpure Integers can't have a decimal point. You'd either need to use a `double` or a `float`.

Comment: @AbhaNagpure No worries, if this answer has helped then please accept it be clicking the ✓ icon underneath the score. This'll mark the question as "answered" and help who see this question others in the future. You can read more information at ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an `if` condition in your increment method

```
plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(count<10){
              addtocart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              count++;
              textcount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            }
            //You can add an else if you want to do something else{}
        }
    });
```

Comment: was just about to say an empty if statement is bad :D

Comment: I was faster :P

Comment: Personally I would check for `>= 10` because someone might increment by more than 1

Comment: @ScaryWombat she says that the max is 10, why should I add a higher or equals than 10 then?

Comment: Would it be better to have a single condition as `if (count < 10) {`? That would get rid of the empty block and the `else`

Comment: It's the same if she has to add something when the count >= 10

Comment: Yep, that's better